# Unable to Turbo boost Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, turbo-boost

I have MBP 13" 2012, my cpu 2.5 Ghz up to 3.1 Ghz but when I use Intel Gadget, the cpu only reach 2.9 Ghz on render and heavy use situation. Is it possible to make cpu reach 3.1 Ghz by terminal command or by an application ?

Answer (score 2):

3,1GHz is a single core maximum. Like when running prime95 on one core.

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html
Intel has a sneaky way of suggesting that it will work on all cores under some conditions but that's just advertising unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There are some more factors playing in the Intel Turbo Boost Game.
New Processors like the i3 i5 i7 Generations from Intel als *intelligent*.

So here are some parameters CPU's are evaluating before going to maniac mode.

- CPU Core Temperatur
- Power Status
- Mainboard Temeratur
- how many cores are used
- and much more

So it isn't easy to explain all of the things but if the CPU Temp is over an certain level - Intel CPU is downclocking - so you won't reach the 3,1GHz - and if you are using Battery Power the System does not allow the energy intensive obove 2,8Ghz.
Also the Turbo Mode is acitvated if only one core need "extrem" CPU Power, because the Heat has to be transfered from the CPU out of the Macbook. So you will get 3,1Ghz only in some circumstances.